# How to separate fields in main screen and ionic modal?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying out the ionic modal to use for editing an item in my app.  on my main screen, i configured a button to open a modal and pass the item details.  here's the html code:

```
                <button class = "button button-block" ng-click = "openModal(item)">
                <div class="row">
                    <item class="col col-15">{{item.itemName}} </item> 
                    <item class="col col-15">{{item.brand}} </item>
                    <item class="col col-5">{{item.size}} </item> 
                    <item class="col col-15">{{item.quantity}}</item>
                    <item class="col col-15">{{item.threshold}}</item>
                </div>
                </button>
```

In my openModal function, I initialize itemdetail to display in my modal as follows:

```
$scope.openModal = function(item) {
    $scope.itemdetail = item;
    $scope.modal.show();
};
```

I am able to display the itemdetail properties in my modal and I have configured 2 fields in the modal as editable:

```
        <form name="inventoryItemModal">
            <div   class="col">

                <item class="row">
                    <item class="col">Brand : {{itemdetail.brand}} </item>
                </item>
                <item class="row">
                    <item class="col">Size : {{itemdetail.size}} </item> 
                </item>
                <item class="row">
                    <div class= "col"> Quantity : &nbsp;
                    <input type="number" ng-model="itemdetail.quantity" step="1" max="99999999" ng-change='fieldchanged=true'>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"> Threshold : &nbsp;
                        <input type="number" ng-model="itemdetail.threshold" min="1" step="1" max="99999999" ng-change='fieldchanged=true'>
                    </div>
                </item>

            </div>
            <button class = "button button-{{colorTheme}}"
                    ng-disabled="!inventoryItemModal.$dirty || inventoryItemModal.$invalid "
                    ng-click = "processItem(itemdetail)">Update</button>
        </form>
```

the problem is when I change the value of the quantity field but then click outside the modal to go back to the main screen, the main screen reflects the value changed in the modal even though I am using different variables in the main screen (item.quantity) and modal screen (itemdetail.quantity).  Why is item.quantity changing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by changing the name of the input field in the modal from quantity to quantitymodal.  I don't know why that is but it works.